# Give permalinks of comments

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, permalink

In [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com) we've been able to permalink snippets of conversation for later use (for example referencing it in another chatroom):

[image]

...which produces a link like this:

> https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/22113950#22113950

I have recently been trying to permalink comments on *posts*, but I've been having a hard time doing it.
These are currently the only ways I know how to permalink comments:

- Wait 'til someone replies to your comment, the SE Network inbox links you to their reply (*bear in mind that this isn't linking to the **specific** comment you want to link to*)
- Flag a comment, go to your Flag History, and then click on the comment you flagged

Only one conclusion:
Can we have access to permalinks of comments directly rather than indirectly via the methods I described above, *please*?

Doing so will make it easy to reference comments elsewhere, for example in the chatrooms (so instead of posting an image of the comment or copying it, I can give a magical link to it).

Comment: Copy the link of the timestamp of a comment.

Comment: @MartijnPieters See the answer I gave. I've already answered the question.

Comment: Also see [Direct Link to a Comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5436)

Comment: I find it amusing that the downvoter DV'd only because this question is marked as a duplicate, even when I self-answered the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered while writing this feature request that this feature is *already there*, it's just hidden.

To obtain the permalink, right-click the timestamp of the comment and copy the link it gives, for example:

[image]

...which in turn gives this direct link to the comment:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29008127/why-are-rust-executables-so-huge/29008355#comment46273028_29008355
```

Comment: Using timestamps as the target of permalinks is a widely held custom.  See most all major blog platforms, twitter, etal.